# Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function in my react js as follows which is fairly simple and returns different values based on conditions.

```
 const checkStatus =(device:any)=> {
        if(device?.patient){
            return "disconnect"
        } else if(!device.patient && device?.status === "DEACTIVATED") {
                return "delete"
        }
            else {
                return "enable"
            }
        }
```

above code throws and error ***"Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."*** . can anyone help me understand what is wrong here

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Pay more attention to the layout to clarify the control flow.

Comment: Are you using this as a react component (in jsx), or calling it as a normal function ?

Comment: its a normal function @EEAH

Comment: Can you provide the context its used in or called ?

Answer (score -1):

You are using the ternary operator in a weird way which could cause the js to not function as intended. Try removing it(note that your code may run differently than intended).

```js
const checkStatus = (device:any) => {
  if (device.patient) {
    return "disconnect";
  } else if (!device.patient && device.status === "DEACTIVATED") {
    return "delete";
  } else {
    return "enable";
  }
}
```

Comment: the `?.` is not the ternary operator. It is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and does not cause JS to not function as intended.

Answer (score -1):

It is not very clear from the question where this function is called. But some problems can be spotted which should lead to errors. Seems what is happening is that function is called in a react component, and its throwing an exception which causes the react component not to reach the return statement of its render thus throwing the exception: **"Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."**

**3 problems can be seen in this function:**

1- you are not checking if the argument `device` if null. If it is null `device.patient` will throw an exception.

2- you are using ternary operator in a weird way. If its to satisfy ts linting, its wrong. This can be avoided by adding a guard clause at the start of the function: `if (!device) return null;`. ts will analyze the control flow and it won't require you to add the ternary operator.

3- if `any` is used with typescript there is something wrong with the function. Why it should expect `any` argument ? Why not an object that have `patient` and `status` as members ?